# What is the Pin Icon called in Material Icons?

Tags: flutter, material-design

What is the name of this **pin** icon?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flutter**'s [`Icon` class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) uses [the icons from Material Design](https://material.io/tools/icons).

The only icons that would come close to the icon from the image you linked are the following:

- [`place`](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=place&style=baseline)
- [`pin_drop`](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=pin_drop&style=baseline)

Alternatively, you could use icons from the [`cupertino_icons`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cupertino_icons) package, however, it [does not feature](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/cupertino_icons/master/map.png) your desired icon either.

Answer (score 9):

Now the exact icon is available in Material Icon.

- Icon Name:  `push_pin`
- Icon Url: https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=push%20pin&icon=push_pin&style=baseline

Image:
[image: Material push icon screenshot]